# Format pivot data with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

My current query is

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT("json_extract_scalar"("data", '$.user_id'))) AS users, event, date(timestamp)
FROM tableName
WHERE category='category'
GROUP BY event, date(timestamp)
ORDER BY date(timestamp) DESC
```

Right now, the output it displays is of the form:

> users  |     date    | event | 
>    3    | 2019-09-25  | visit | 
>    4    | 2019-09-25  | click_button | 
>    10   | 2019-09-25  | visit |

I want it to be of the form

> | date    |     users_visits |     users_clicks | 
>   |2019-09-25 | 3       | 4 | 
>   |2019-09-26 | 10      | 0 |

I wrote this query but it does not work, I don't understand really how to get the counting query inside the pivoting query properly

```
SELECT date(timestamp), [visit] AS users_visits, [click_button] AS users_clicks
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ("json_extract_scalar"("data", '$.user_id')), event, date(timestamp)
    FROM tableName
    WHERE category='category'
    GROUP BY event, date(timestamp) 
  )
  ) P
PIVOT 
(
  COUNT (DISTINCT  ("json_extract_scalar"("data", '$.user_id')))
  FOR event in 
  ([visit], [click_button])
  ) AS pvt
 order by pvt.date(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does conditional aggregation work?

```
SELECT date(timestamp),
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN event = 'visit'
                           THEN "json_extract_scalar"("data", '$.user_id')
                      END) as visits,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN event = 'click_button'
                           THEN "json_extract_scalar"("data", '$.user_id')
                      END) as click_button
FROM tableName
WHERE category = 'category'
GROUP BY date(timestamp)
ORDER BY date(timestamp) DESC
```

Comment: Yes, it does! You have repeated the 'then' keyword but otherwise, it works perfectly, thank you very much!